# htaccess: How to allow access only to one file, otherwise request index.php?

Tags: .htaccess, web, mod-rewrite

How can I allow access only to one file, otherwise request `index.php` using `.htaccess`?

I need to allow access only to file `update.php`. If it's not this file, then just access index.php.
I tried this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^update\.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it allows access to all files. I don't know why.
Hope for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shown samples could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(!?update\.php).*$ - [NC,F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```